# ROS_ERROS STREAM in Python

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to know what is the equivalent of the function ROS_ERROR_STREAM in python

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270072/ros_erros-stream-in-python/) by [Younès](https://answers.ros.org/users/29249/youn%C3%A8s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess that would be `rospy.logerr(..)`.

See [wiki/rospy/Logging](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Logging).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Younès](https://answers.ros.org/users/29249/youn%C3%A8s/) on 2017-09-08**:
thank you ok